# Sequelize filter for properties of hasMany association in where clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, associations, eager-loading

I have the following models:

```
const Machine = sequelize.define('Machine', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const Review = sequelize.define('Review', { ReviewDate: DataTypes.DATEONLY });

Review.belongsTo(Machine);
Machine.hasMany(Review);
```

Now I want to get all machines where the last review date is older than 3 months.

```
const reviewOverdueDate = new Date();
reviewOverdueDate.setMonth(reviewOverdueDate.getMonth() - 3);

const request = {
  include: [{
    model: Review,
    order: [
      ["ReviewDate", "DESC"]
    ],
    limit: 1
  }],
  where: {
    // this obviously does not work, because the included Review is an array
    // but maybe there is some syntax to access the first entry in that array?
    '$Review.ReviewDate$': { [Op.gt]: reviewOverdueDate }
  }


Machine.findAndCountAll(request)
```

How do I write a proper where clause to achieve the goal? Is there a way to use the `$nested.column$` syntax to access lists/arrays?

I got it working with a sequelize literal in the where clause

```
where: {
  Sequelize.literal(`('${reviewOverdueDate.toISOString()}' > (SELECT "ReviewDate" FROM 
  "Review" WHERE "Review"."MachineID" = "Machine"."ID" ORDER BY 
  "Review"."ReviewDate" DESC LIMIT 1))`)
}
```

But I like to have it in sequelize notation and use the hasMany association.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the where clause inside de include?

```
const request = {
  include: [{
    model: Review,
    order: [
      ["ReviewDate", "DESC"]
    ],
    limit: 1,
    where: {
      ReviewDate: { [Op.gt]: reviewOverdueDate }
    }
  }]
```